# Live notifications using PlayFab

Tags: unity, c#, playfab

I want to integrate live notification, send/receive, in my Unity game using the PlayFab server. Is there an API call for this?

Comment: There is a full guide right away at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/engagement/push-notifications/quickstart. Have you taken a look at it and are struggeling with some point?